# What is a good article on Hume's view on causality?

Tags: causation, hume

Could anyone please let me know of a good review article that gives
and overview of Hume's view on causality?

Comment: Outside of encyclopedia articles from WP or SEP? --Maybe you can indicate what sort of text you might be interested in? --It sounds like "introductory", but it would definitely help focus this question a bit if you could explain what might have made this concern interesting or important to you

Comment: Thats actually not a bad source but hume's work on that explained there shortly. We have a journal club on causality and that is the reason that our group is interested on a good review of his work on causality.

Comment: You can see also [Hume on causality](http://www.iep.utm.edu/hume-cau).

Comment: See also [Hume on causation](http://cw.routledge.com/textbooks/alevelphilosophy/data/A2/Hume/HumeCausation.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alexander Rosenberg, “Hume and the Philosophy of Science” in Norton, ed. *The Cambridge Companion to Hume.* Cambridge UP, 1993. Describes the theory with useful intellectual context.

Comment: Nope, it's not a book, though; it's a short article IN a book.